# How to highlight the words in a wordPuzzle game in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a course project how to build a Word Puzzle.

Until now, I have implemented and executed the code how to display the words in a grid in a random position and how to fill it with random letters after the words are placed in the grid. Now I am stuck because I do not know how to proceed in order to highlight the words as in the image below [Word Puzzle Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QenSE.png). What modifier should I use or other functions? Which are the steps in general? Any idea would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: you could look into using `AttributedString` to color your specific words.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.